# Why is counter_cache column not increasing when << an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, counter-cache

Given I have the following models:

```
class Location < Active::Record
  has_many :storables, foreign_key: :bin_id
  # ...
end

class Storable < Active::Record
  belongs_to :bin, class_name: :Location, counter_cache: true
  # ...
end
```

When I run the following spec, the `counter_cache` doesn't increment correctly. Method `#1` and `#2` work as expected, but NOT `#3`. What gives?

```
describe "location storables" do
  specify "adding a storable increments the counter cache" do
    l = Location.create
    l.storables_count.should == 0 #=> PASSES

    # method 1
    s = Storable.create(bin: l)
    l.reload
    l.storables_count.should == 1 #=> PASSES

    # method 2
    l.storables.create
    l.reload
    l.storables_count.should == 2 #=> PASSES

    # method 3
    l.storables << Storable.create
    l.reload
    l.storables_count.should == 3 #=> FAILS, got 2 not 3
  end
end
```

I'm really confused by the **counter_cache half working**. I can't spot a configuration problem either.

Using **Rails 3.2.12** on this project.

**UPDATE**

Upgrading to **rails 4** didn't help. Also, if I change method #3 to the following, the test passes:

```
# method 3
l.storables << Storable.create
puts "proxy    : #{l.storables.count}" #=> 3
puts "relation : #{Storable.count}"    #=> 3
puts "cache    : #{l.storables_count}"    #=> 2

Location.reset_counters(l.id, :storables) # corrects cache

l.reload
l.storables_count.should == 3 #=> PASSES
```

Why isn't this happening automatically?

Comment: Regarding the accepted answer, I'm seeing the same behaviour with ``l.storables << Storable.last``, which is probably worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, I don't think it's appropriate to write something like `l.storables << Storable.create`.

By writing this, two things happens:

1. `Storable.create` creates a new Storable object with `location_id` nil
2. `l.storables <<` updates the object created, sets location_id to `l.id`, and somehow forgets to update the counter cache.

It might be ActiveRecord's fault, since it should have been smarter, but you've actually executed two SQL(insert into storable & update storable set location_id = something) simply to insert a new storable record. Anyway it's a bad idea, and if you have a foreign key constraint on location_id, the first insert would even fail.

So use `l.storables << Storable.new` instead

PS: With `l.storables << Storable.create`, since the return value of `Storable.create` is not a new record, it's a bit hard for `l` to decide what to do. In some cases, it needs to increment its own counter cache, in other cases, it needs to increment its own counter cache and decrement someone else's counter cache, or it might need to do nothing.

Comment: It's too bad AR doesn't understand this. Thanks for narrowing the issue down for me! I've been digging around for previous work on supporting the 'create' use case and the counter_culture gem looks like it may fit. This test seems to support exactly this case: (https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/blob/master/spec/counter_culture_spec.rb#L12).